# Перемещение элемента из блока в блок

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать перемещение выбранного элемента в нужное место по клику на него?
Вот живой пример https://www.fantasydraft.com/contest/831451/
В левом блоке выбираем элемент - кликаем на стрелочку - он отображается в правом блоке (точнее перемещается).
Создаю сайт для себя и небольшой компании друзей. Решил писать на phph, но времени на изучение не хватает. Поэтому прошу помочь, стараюсь находить готовые примеры и реализовывать их по мере необходимости. Может найдется волонтер, который подскажет на примере как это делается?

Comment: А `php` при чем тут?

Comment: читайте про `drag and drop`.

Comment: может и так, javascript я не знаю. Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: разве в примере приведенном мной выше реализовано перетаскивание? Там клик по кнопке и перемещение в другой блок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается средствами JavaScript, как и любая интерактивность на стороне клиента (а PHP - язык для серверных скриптов, на нем сделать такое не получится).

Реализовать можно использованием метода элемента [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) в [слушателе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) события [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click).

```js
// выбираем из DOM два родительских элемента, между которыми будем перемещать дочерние
var setL = document.getElementById('left'),
    setR = document.getElementById('right'); 
// заполнение дочерними элементами, для простоты примера, они будут строчными (это не имеет значения: с блоками принцип тот же)
for (let el, colorSt, i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    colorSt = `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 360)}, 100%, 67%)`; 
    setL.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span style="background-color: ${colorSt}"></span>`); 
  }, i * 33); 
}
// добавляем обработчик клика родительским элементам
setL.addEventListener('click', onSetElemClick);
setR.addEventListener('click', onSetElemClick);

// обработчик, логика которого крайне проста: если цель (дочерний элемент) не в родителе с которым сравниваем - перемещаем в него
function onSetElemClick(e) {
  switch (e.target.parentElement.id) {
    case 'left' : setR.appendChild(e.target); break; 
    case 'right': setL.appendChild(e.target); 
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

.set {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1.4em); min-height: calc(100vh - 30px); 
  display: inline-flex; flex-wrap: wrap; 
  align-content: flex-start; 
  padding: 0.3em; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px 0 #0002; 
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.set span {
  width: 3em; height: 3em; margin: 0.3em; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -2px #0004; 
  transition: transform, 0.2s ease-out; 
}
.set span:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="set"></div>
  <div id="right" class="set"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Буду разбираться, как все это применить в моем случае.

Comment: @Foliant, не нужно применять *все* - в тексте ответа четко указано, что нужно применить: прослушивать событие клика, реагируя на него перемещением элемента через `appendChild()`. Это все что минимально необходимо в рамках задачи. Если что-то неясно - напишите что именно, и я дополню ответ. Пример - является именно примером... это не код для копирования, а демонстрация.

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил ваш комментарий с фразой _"javascript я не знаю"_... такую информацию следует указывать **в вопросе**. С учетом ее, мой ответ не имеет смысла (и его заминусят; а ваш вопрос - вероятно, удалят).

Comment: Прошу прощения, раз так получилось. Видимо мне действительно нужно поглубже познакомится с правилами сайта. Я верно понимаю, что здесь нет такого функционала как "написать в личку"?

Comment: @Foliant, все ок :) Если бы меня беспокоила перспектива получить несколько минусов - удалил бы свой ответ (он может пригодиться сообществу, поэтому пусть будет). Вопросу своему Вы можете помочь, попробовав решить задачу и добавив в вопрос [mcve]. Дело в том что здесь не приветствуются "сделайте за меня" вместо вопросов... А вот когда человек пытается что-то сделать самостоятельно, он может получить совет и/или объяснение. По поводу лички - верно, тут ее нет: это все-таки вопросный сайт, он не для переписок (и на случай если хотите предложить работу, сразу оговорюсь что не занимаюсь таким).

Comment: спасибо за разьяснения